# Updating the main form's progress bar from an external class?

Tags: c#, class, progress-bar

I have a main form with a progress bar on it, and I would like to update the progress bar from an external class called "Logic"... however, Logic is already being referenced to on the main form. If I try to reference the main form in the Logic to update the progress bar, I just get stack overflows.

While searching around, I came across a lot of topics about a BackgroundWorker... but that's not what I'm trying to use. I have specific places in my Logic class where I want to update the progress bar on the main form by using progressbar.PerformStep(). I've tried creating a method on the main form to update the progress bar and calling that from the Logic class, but once again it's lacking a reference... and I can't just use MainForm frm1 = new MainForm() without causing errors everywhere else. I'm feeling pretty stumped here.

[edit]

Here is the code with the solution (thanks to you guys)----

Main Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Natural_Language_Processor
{
public partial class frm_Main : Form

{
    Logic logic = new Logic();

    public frm_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void btn_Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logic.Progress += new Logic.ProgressDelegate(DisplayProgess);
        logic.RaiseProgress(0);

        logic.str_Input = txt_Input.Text;
        logic.Prep_Input();

        txt_Input.Text = "";
        logic.RaiseProgress(100);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        logic.RaiseProgress(0);
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void eraseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logic.EraseMemory();
    }

    public void DisplayProgess(int percent)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Logic.ProgressDelegate(DisplayProgess), new Object[] { percent });
        }
        else
        {
            this.progbar.Value = percent;
        }
    }
}
```

Logic:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Natural_Language_Processor
{
class Logic
{
    Data oData = new Data();
    public List<string> Words = new List<string>();

    private System.Threading.Thread T = null;

    public delegate void ProgressDelegate(int percent);
    public event ProgressDelegate Progress;

    #region Variables
        public string str_Input;
        public string[] WordArray;
    #endregion

    public void RaiseProgress(int percent)
    {
        if (Progress != null)
        {
            Progress(percent);
        }
    }

    public void Prep_Input()
    {
        //Check for Input
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str_Input))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //Set everything to lower-case
            str_Input = str_Input.ToLower();
            RaiseProgress(10);

            //Remove all punctuation
            if (str_Input.Contains(","))
            {
                while (str_Input.Contains(","))
                {
                    int int_index = str_Input.IndexOf(",");
                    str_Input = str_Input.Remove(int_index, 1);
                }
            }
            if (str_Input.EndsWith("."))
            {
                str_Input = str_Input.Trim('.');
            }
            else if (str_Input.EndsWith("?"))
            {
                str_Input = str_Input.Trim('?');
            }
            RaiseProgress(20);

            //Split the sentence into an array of individual words
            WordArray = str_Input.Split(' ');
            RaiseProgress(30);

            //Get current words (and max ID) from the database
            int max_index = 0;
            oData.GetWords();
            Words.Clear();

            if (oData.WordDataSet.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < oData.WordDataSet.Count; i++)
                {
                    max_index = oData.WordDataSet[i].ID;
                    Words.Add(oData.WordDataSet[i].Word);
                }
            }
            RaiseProgress(40);

            //Check each word in the sentence
            for (int i = 0; i < WordArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //Update the frequency of an existing word in the database
                if (Words.Contains(WordArray[i].ToString()))
                {
                    oData.UpdateWords(WordArray[i].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Or add the word
                    max_index = max_index + 1;
                    oData.InsertWordsTable(max_index, WordArray[i].ToString(), 1);

                    //And create its pre/pro word tables
                    oData.NewPreWordTable(WordArray[i].ToString());
                    oData.NewProWordTable(WordArray[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            RaiseProgress(50);

            //Check each word in the sentence after we have possibly created new pre/pro word tables in the previous code
            for (int i = 1; i < WordArray.Length; i++)
            {
                oData.GetPreWords(WordArray[i].ToString());
                Words.Clear();

                //Get current pre_words from the database
                for (int a = 0; a < oData.WordDataSet.Count; a++)
                {
                    Words.Add(oData.WordDataSet[a].Word);
                }

                //Update the frequency of an existing word in the database
                if (Words.Contains(WordArray[i - 1].ToString()))
                {
                    oData.UpdatePreWords(WordArray[i].ToString(), WordArray[i - 1].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Or add the word
                    oData.InsertPreWord(WordArray[i].ToString(), oData.GetPreWordIndex(WordArray[i].ToString()), WordArray[i - 1].ToString(), 1);
                }

                if (i == WordArray.Length - 1)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    oData.GetProWords(WordArray[i].ToString());
                    Words.Clear();

                    //Get current pro_words from the database
                    for (int b = 0; b < oData.WordDataSet.Count; b++)
                    {
                        Words.Add(oData.WordDataSet[b].Word);
                    }

                    //Update the frequency of an existing word in the database
                    if (Words.Contains(WordArray[i + 1].ToString()))
                    {
                        oData.UpdateProWords(WordArray[i].ToString(), WordArray[i + 1].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Or add the word
                        oData.InsertProWord(WordArray[i].ToString(), oData.GetProWordIndex(WordArray[i].ToString()), WordArray[i + 1].ToString(), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            RaiseProgress(60);
        }
    }

    public void Respond()
    {
        RaiseProgress(70);
    }

    public void EraseMemory()
    {
        oData.GetWords();
        Words.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < oData.WordDataSet.Count; i++)
        {
            oData.DeletePreTable(oData.WordDataSet[i].Word);
            oData.DeleteProTable(oData.WordDataSet[i].Word);
        }
        oData.DeleteWordsTable();
        MessageBox.Show("Memory has been erased.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you could use a delegate to update the progress bar from the Logic class.

Comment: Show some of the code where you keep these *references*, and definitely include where you are getting that stack overflow exception.

Comment: try looking at Background Worker with Progress Bar [Background Worker with ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Form1 references Form2, the progress bar is on Form1 and I need Form2 to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a loosely coupled approach, with the Logic() class raising a custom event instead of directly referencing the Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logic logic = new Logic();
        logic.Progress += new Logic.ProgressDelegate(DisplayProgess);
        logic.Start();
    }

    public void DisplayProgess(string message, int percent)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Logic.ProgressDelegate(DisplayProgess), new Object[] { message, percent });
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Text = message;
            this.progressBar1.Value = percent;
        }
    }

}

public class Logic
{

    private System.Threading.Thread T = null;

    public delegate void ProgressDelegate(string message, int percent);
    public event ProgressDelegate Progress;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (T == null)
        {
            T = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Worker));
            T.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        RaiseProgress("Initializing...", 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulated work

        RaiseProgress("Loading Map...", 25);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500); // simulated work

        RaiseProgress("Loading Sprites...", 50);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200); // simulated work

        RaiseProgress("Loading Sound Effects...", 75);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1700);

        RaiseProgress("Loading Music...", 85);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1100); // simulated work

        RaiseProgress("Done!", 100);
    }

    private void RaiseProgress(string message, int percent)
    {
        if (Progress != null)
        {
            Progress(message, percent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that for making my progress bar take a step at particular points in my logic code.

Comment: I want the progress bar to actually represent progress, not just simulate it. Neat code, though.

Comment: In my example, the main form has created an instance of Logic() and subscribed to its Progress() event.  In Logic(), you simply call RaiseProgress() and pass it a message and percent complete whenever you need to update progress.  The main form will receive the event and update itself accordingly.  Of course I had to "simulate" the progess...I don't know what your app is actually doing!  =)

Comment: lol yeah, after spreading it out and tinkering a little it did the trick :D

Comment: My fiance says you deserve a hug XD